# Using (&) + element as an iterator c++

Tags: c++

```
vector <int> n ;
n.push_back(10);
n.push_back(10) ;
n.push_back(10) ;
cout <<accumulate(&n[0],&n[2],0) ;
```

It doesn't work , but can I use something like this where I refer to the element instead of iterators ?

Comment: You do know that `std:vector` have functions to get the starting and end iterators?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/cNhjt4).

Comment: @angew It wont work on implementations that use a proxy, such as (IIRC) MSVC in debug mode.

Comment: @Angew The OP probably wants 30 as result

Comment: In what way does it not work? Pointers to start and end of a contiguous range are valid as iterators, by design.

Comment: @user1781290 Then they better say so. You're probably right, but I'd never have guessed it myself.

Comment: @KazDragon Then that implementation is non-conforming. The standard guarantees this to work.

Comment: There's no reason for this not to work, but every reason not to do it. Iterators will be just as efficient and easier for someone else reading the code to see what's going on. If the purpose is to get access to the underlying C array (to pass to a C library or something), then use `std::vector::data()` to make it clear what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers have random iterator semantics, and `std::vector` guarantees contiguity of elements, so using pointers to vector elements as iterators is perfectly fine (actually, `std::vector<T>::iterator` could be implemented directly with pointers).

The point is that you are probably using a wrong range. You want:

```
accumulate(&n[0],&n[3],0)
```

Remember that ranges in STL algorithms are intended as semi-open, i.e. you refer to the sequence [begin, end) (=the "end" element is not included). For this reason, the `end()` iterator used in "STL" actually points to *one element after the last*.

Notice that the snippet above is probably not legal, since I am (formally) dereferencing a nonexisting element (it's allowed to have a pointer to one element past the last in an array, but not to dereference it); the correct form would be:

```
accumulate(&n[0],&n[0] + 3,0)
```

But typically there's no reason not to use "regular" `std::vector` iterators:

```
accumulate(n.begin(),n.end(),0)
```

or, if you actually just want the first three elements (regardless of the total size of the vector):

```
accumulate(n.begin(),n.begin()+3,0)
```

Comment: This is sort of unrelated but can you explain the difference between accumulate(&n[0],&n[3],0) and accumulate(&n[0],&n[0] + 3,0). I thought that these were the same thing

Comment: @NathanWride: it is invalid to use the expression `n[3]` on a vector `n` that has only 3 elements.

Comment: Ok I get that but what about n[0]+3, isn't that the same as n[3]?

Comment: @NathanWride `n[3]` says "get me the value of the thing in the fourth slot", i.e. it implies a dereference (actually, a function call on a `std::vector`). `&n[3]` gets the value and then takes its address. On the other hand, `&n[0] + 3` gets the address of the first element (valid for a non-empty container) and then bumps the pointer address by three places -- no dereferencing of the invalid location occurs.